# How to build QT 4.8.7 For 32-bit

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit). I want to build QT 4.8.7 Source code for 32-bit. How to configure the build?

Comment: Did you consider using `chroot` on a `debootstrap`-ed virtual 32 bits file tree and distribution (so build your application in 32 bits there)? It probably is the simplest way

Comment: Did not try that. I have not used chroot ever. Could you please help me to configure it?

Comment: Read about `schroot` & `debootstrap`

Comment: However I would prefer to build the code using ./configure <config parameter 32-bit> of QT4.8.7 for 32 bit. I have already build all other libraries (gtest, boost etc in 32 bit without chroot)  in 32-bit which are required for my Application.

Comment: Why? That would be much harder (you'll need to build *all* the dependencies in 32 bits before building Qt itself). STFW for *Linux From Scratch*

Answer (score 0):

Well if all solutions in the comments fail. Do it as me in VirtualBox. Install 32b operating system there and build what you want.